# Is there a GCP service that could be used as EKM for MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, encryption-asymmetric, google-cloud-kms

I have an SQL Server on Google Compute's VM. I would like to use Extensible Key Management. The requirement is to have everything in GCP. Ideally I would like Google Cloud Platform to be the provider of EKM. Otherwise I will have to install a third party EKM in GCP.

I looked into Google KMS but I cannot see any integration with SQL Server.
I cannot find any info about other Google services being able to manage keys and to integrate with MS SQL Server.

I am struggling to find any answers on Google.

Is there a GCP service that could do that?

UPDATE:
MS SQL Server has multiple databases. I would like to have each database encrypted with a different key and allow for a regular change of keys.

Comment: Can you check if [customer-managed encryption keys (CMEK)](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/configure-cmek) address your question?

Comment: From what I have read and understood it can be used only with Cloud SQL.

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/customer-managed-encryption may meet your needs. This page describes how to use CMEK keys from KMS on a Compute VM and which parts of the VM are protected.

Comment: Thanks, I believe CMEK would allow me to encrypt a VM or a persistent disk. However my SQL Server has multiple databases and each db needs a different encryption. I am not sure if this could be applied in such scenario? Maybe if each database had a separate persistent disk but I do not think this is a practice used in managing SQL servers.